# перебор массива через this постоянно возвращает -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

почему в данной конструкции постоянно возвращается -1? Как заставить this работать корректно? Помогите пжлст

```
var arr = ["q", "w", "e"],
    arr2 = ["e", "w", "q"];
jQuery.each(arr2, function() {
    alert($.inArray(this, arr));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Верный код:**

```
var arr = ["q", "w", "e"],
    arr2 = ["e", "w", "q"];
jQuery.each(arr2, function(i, val) {
    alert($.inArray(val, arr));
});
```

Значение элеменета массива хранится в переменной **val**, а **this** - сам элемент. **i** - номер элемента массива.

Comment: _this - сам элемент_ - какой элемент, и чем он отличается от элемента массива _val_?

Comment: @Grundy тем, что это объект, а не строка. Сравнение объекта со стракой очевидно даёт неравенство.

Comment: но это разве не элемент массива? :)

Comment: @Grundy элемент, про что я и написал. Элемент имеет определённое значение. И запрашивать надо значение, если вы ищите по значениям. Не занимайтесь казуистикой.

Comment: мне кажется вы запутались, в `this` и `val` передается одно и то же значение. Поэтому говорить что в _в переменной val - значение, а в this - элемент_ не верно

Comment: @Grundy да, я прочитал ваш ответ. Но это никак не отменяет того факта, что в `this` передаётся объект. Более того, в другом языке может быть другая структура массива, в которой элемент массива может быть **не** равен значению в принципе. Потому топикстартеру важно научиться различать эти понятия во избежании подобных проблем в будущем. Если вы ищите значение - запрашивайте значение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33269/discussion-between-grundy-and-risto).

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вопрос более интересен, чем может показаться на первый взгляд.

Если посмотреть [исходники `each`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L284), то можно увидеть как вызывается *callback*

```
( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );
```

Таким образом видно, что в качестве контекста *this* и второго параметра *val* передается одно и то же значение.

Ниже пример, в котором видно, что это действительно одно и то же.

```js
var arr = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}, {
  a: 3
}];
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  console.log(this, value, this === value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в случае из вопроса элементы массива - это примитивы.

При передаче в качестве контекста примитив оборачивается в объект, то есть вместо строки `'s'` будет передан объект `String('s')`

```js
var arr=['a','b','c'],
    arr2=[1,2,3];

jQuery.each(arr,function(index, value){
  console.log(this, value, this===value);
  //решением для строк может стать перевод в строку
  var a = this+'',
      b = this.toString();
  console.log("this+'':",a, value, a===value, 'this.toString():',b, value, b===value);
});
jQuery.each(arr2,function(index, value){
  console.log(this, value, this===value);
  //решением для числа может стать перевод в число
  var a = +this,
      b = parseInt(this,10);//или parseFloat
  console.log("+this:",a, value, a===value, 'parseInt(this,10):',b, value, b===value);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Альтернативное решение: использовать ["use strict"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

В этом случае `this` передается как есть, а не оборачивается в массив:

```js
var arr = ["q", "w", "e"],
  arr2 = ["e", "w", "q"];
jQuery.each(arr2, function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log($.inArray(this, arr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```